# Не отображается ячейка в столбце

Tags: javascript, html, html5

При отправке списка, нет данных в столбце "23". 25 елементов в списке что отправляю, потому как раз все должно отображаться, но нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Через инспектор страницы видно что значение получил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но визуально нет даже границ ячейки. Пробовал удалять css и скрипты, оставлял только эту табл на странице - результат тот же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Two Pages</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul.tabs {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #333;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        ul.tabs li {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            color: #fff;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }

        ul.tabs li:hover {
            background-color: #555;
        }

        .tab-content {
            display: none;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        h1 {
            color: #333;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        input {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        #suggestions {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          max-height: 200px;
          overflow-y: auto;
          background-color: #fff;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-top: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header style="background-color: #333; color: #fff">
    </header>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li onclick="showPage(1)">Користувачі</li>
        <li onclick="showPage(2)">Повідомлення</li>
        <li onclick="showPage(3)">Статуси</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content" id="page3">
        <h1>Статуси</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>00</th>
                    <th>01</th>
                    <th>02</th>
                    <th>03</th>
                    <th>04</th>
                    <th>05</th>
                    <th>06</th>
                    <th>07</th>
                    <th>08</th>
                    <th>09</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>11</th>
                    <th>12</th>
                    <th>13</th>
                    <th>14</th>
                    <th>15</th>
                    <th>16</th>
                    <th>17</th>
                    <th>18</th>
                    <th>19</th>
                    <th>20</th>
                    <th>21</th>
                    <th>22</th>
                    <th>23</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>2023-10-06</td>
                        <td>name</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                    </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
      function showPage(pageNumber) {
          const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
          const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');

          pages.forEach(page => {
              page.style.display = 'none';
          });

          tabs.forEach(tab => {
              tab.classList.remove('active-tab');
          });

          document.getElementById(`page${pageNumber}`).style.display = 'block';
          tabs[pageNumber - 1].classList.add('active-tab');
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: видать количество ячеек не совпадает.

Comment: Посчитал, да, не совпадает

Comment: @BlackStar1991 25 столбцов, 25 елементов в списке
наполняю через {% for message in status_list %} ... {% endfor %}

Comment: Вставьте сюда код таблицы из инспектора, чтоб можно было воспроизвести

Comment: @ГрибовПавел Добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересчитай теги =)

Заголовков 26, ячеек - 25

Answer (score 2):

Если вы там циклом выводите, то там наверное надо учитывать заголовок

```css
th:nth-child(even){
  background-color: pink;
}

td:nth-child(even){
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>name</th>
       <th>00</th>
       <th>01</th>
       <th>02</th>
       <th>03</th>
       <th>04</th>
       <th>05</th>
       <th>06</th>
       <th>07</th>
       <th>08</th>
       <th>09</th>
       <th>10</th>
       <th>11</th>
       <th>12</th>
       <th>13</th>
       <th>14</th>
       <th>15</th>
       <th>16</th>
       <th>17</th>
       <th>18</th>
       <th>19</th>
       <th>20</th>
       <th>21</th>
       <th>22</th>
       <th>23</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

     <tr>
       <td>2023-10-06</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>0</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>
       <td>-</td>

       <td>этой у вас нету</td>
     </tr>

   </tbody>
 </table>
```